# How to define the slug of another model in myListView

Tags: django

I sort of need help understanding my own code specifically the views.py. I'm trying to change url pattern for my TitleUpdateListView from using my Update models title field and instead using the slug field instead.

If someone could help explain line by line whats going in in my TitleUpdateListView so I could better understand whats specifically going on that would be great.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Update view for each game
    path('<str:title>/updates/', TitleUpdateListView.as_view(), name='title-updates'),
    # Adds the ability to sort by platform
    path('<str:title>/updates/<int:platform_id>/', TitleUpdateAjaxListView.as_view(), name='title-updates-ajax'),

]
```

views.py

```
class TitleUpdateListView(ListView):
    model = Update
    context_object_name = 'updates'
    template_name = 'updates/title_updates.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Update.objects.filter(game=title).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitleUpdateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return context


class TitleUpdateAjaxListView(ListView):
    model = Update
    template_name = 'updates/updates_ajax.html'
    context_object_name = 'updates'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Update.objects.filter(game=title, platform=Platform.objects.filter(
            id=self.kwargs.get('platform_id')).first()).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitleUpdateAjaxListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: From your question, one would assume that you actually wanted to understand what's going on in the code, but from the selected answer it seems that you just wanted the correct code, after all. No problem with that, but in the future try to be straight about it from the beginning, so you get your answer faster and nobody wastes time writing stuff you're not actually looking for.

Comment: That's my bad, sorry. I just realized you cant mark multiple correct answers. I originally marked yours and then marked the other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by "I'm trying to change url pattern for my TitleUpdateListView from using my Update models title field and instead using the slug field instead.". In the urls.py, you can change the name of the parameter (the xxxx in `<str:xxxx>`) to whatever you want, as long as you also look for this same name in the view. You can change it to `<str:slug>` and in your view you'd fetch it like `self.kwargs.get('slug')`. Just remember to also change which parameter are you using to filter the `Game` table (`slug` instead of `title`).

As for explaining what your view does, you should probably take a look at Django's docs on Class Based Views, but I'll try to give an overview:

The `get_queryset` method is searching the `Game` table to find the games whose title matches the title passed in the URL parameter. It then returns a list of all `Update` objects whose `game` field points to the game just found.

The `get_context_data` method is adding the same `Game` object found in the `get_queryset` method to the view's context under the `'game'` key. This means that you can access the `Game` object inside the template that this view renders.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `get_queryset` method of your view:

```
# change url variable name from title to slug
path('<str:slug>/updates/', TitleUpdateListView.as_view(), name='title-updates'),
```

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # the url variables are stored in the dictionary self.kwargs
    slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')  
    game = get_object_or_404(Game, slug=slug)
    return Update.objects.filter(game=game).order_by('-date_published')
```

The same applies for `get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(TitleUpdateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    return context
```